# How to discover all other instances of my application on the local Windows network?

Tags: c++, windows, qt, network-programming

We want to add a 'collaborative' feature to our application, so our program should be able to automatically discover all other instances of itself that are running on the same local network, without needing any extra configuration from the users.

Our application runs on Windows, so it can use any APIs provided by the OS. We are assuming a network typical for a small business, a couple of Windows PCs, some routers, etc.

Also, will there be problems with anti-viruses, firewalls, and such? We don't want to scare our users.

Comment: I am not sure, but could this technology be helpful: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bonjour_(software) ?

Comment: It works on Windows too: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bonjour_(software)#Other_implementations

Comment: WixToolset.org on how to write a proper Windows Installer package that will take care of the firewall exception registration.  From Wix, you can make a proper MSI and/or Setup.exe that won't scare your users.

Comment: @selbie: You don't actually need a firewall exception. The goal is to avoid setting off alarms while probing the local network, which by definition does not have firewalls in the middle - just on the edges.

Comment: @MSalters I assumed that Bonjour would also needs to listen at a port, otherwise how can it find the other instances? I assume that every instance uses the broadcast address, and every instance also listens for broadcasts from other instances. Isn't that how Bonjour works?

Comment: @sashoalm: I was responding to @ selbie's comment, which is entirely unrelated to Bonjour. @ vahancho might know more about Bonjor.

Comment: @vahancho Important question: Is Bonjour free to use? Do I need to obtain a license from Apple?

Comment: @sashoalm, although Bonjour is a free software, according to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bonjour_(software)#Licensing - yes, you need to have a license agreement with Apple, if you need to redistribute it yourself.

Comment: @vahancho That would be a deal-breaker. But it says that mDNSResponder source code is Apache 2.0 license, which allows commercial use, so if I only need to use mDNSResponder I'm OK. Do I need to use any other parts of the Bonjour SDK to achieve the needed functionality?

Comment: @sashoalm, I cannot answer on your last question because of having no experience in working with Bonjour so closely. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

You can send [broadcast](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broadcast_traffic) packets for that but that only works within a single subnet (actually apparently a "[broadcast domain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broadcast_domain)" but it's usually the subnet). If you just try every IP you can think of you might trigger firewall pop-ups that suggest that your software is trying to hack the computer. I think the best way is to use broadcast for the current subnet and offer a user interface for adding other hosts.

Comment: What about Bonjour, as suggested by @vahancho? Is it a viable alternative?

Comment: Using Bonjour is probably a much better idea. :)

Comment: Btw, I tried with broadcasting, but it didn't work - it seems that [Windows 7 now blocks broadcasts to 255.255.255.255](http://serverfault.com/questions/72112/how-to-alter-the-global-broadcast-address-255-255-255-255-behavior-on-windows) because they are considered a security risk. So that would make broadcasting a no-go for me.